# How to disable Control running in background

Tags: c#, wpf, button, panel, mainwindow

i have a page transition control in the MainWindow ( theres few buttons and a home button that leads to the homepage), so i click a button on the MainWindow that brings a user control page inside the page transition within the MainWindow , theres an audio to be played in that user control page , ok fine but when i click the home button to show the homepage , the audio from that user control page is still playing . How can i stop the user control page from running in the background?

this is how i call the user control page into the page transition control in the mainwindow :

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Story
    {
        Story page = new Story();
        pageTransition1.IsEnabled = true;
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(page);
    }


    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Home Button
    {
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.IsEnabled = false;
        grid1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

Basically i just want the user control page to stop running ( cos its running in the background) when i click the home button.

How i play my sound in my user control page ::

```
            mediaElement1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
        mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(audioNames[iCurrentImageCount], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        mediaElement1.Play();
```

and

```
     MediaPlayer ap = new MediaPlayer();
        recordedaudio = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"../../Audio/", "*.wav");
        if (recordedaudio == null)
        { MessageBox.Show("No Recorded Files!"); }
        else
        {
            ap.Open(new Uri(recordedaudio[iCurrentImageCount], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            ap.Play();
        }
```

Comment: Is that possible for you to use .Net 4.5? If yes I'll Provide a listing with Async/Await

Comment: this can't be done in 4.0?

Comment: What do you mean? why it can't be done in .Net 4.0?

Comment: i am using .net 4.0 , so the solution to this can only be done in 4.5?

Comment: Can you provide some more code about how you play the sound in your user page?

Comment: the code is huge , theres 2 audio , 1 is the audio that i am going to play , another is a recorded audio by the user.

Comment: I want just the part of the code that is in charge of playing the sound. what is the player and how do you make use of that?

Comment: check my updates , actually i have stop buttons in that user control page but i need to stop it before clicking home button outside of the page transition control , i want to do it like clicking the home button in the mainwindow stops everything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33744/discussion-between-mehrdad-kamelzadeh-and-user2376998)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to handle the Unloaded event in the user control page and stop playing the media.

Comment: private void Grid_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ap.Stop();
            ap.Close();
        } This code will work only if you are loading and unloading the page. If you are just changing the visibility, use IsVisibleChanged event.

Comment: so its something like if UserControlPage_IsVisibleChanged( object sender , RoutedEventArgs e) ?